# Can a Portuguese national ID card be used for travel from the UK to Germany?

Tags: uk, germany, eu-citizens, identity-cards, portuguese-citizens

Next month I am going on holiday to Germany. I am a Portuguese citizen who lives in the UK and I am travelling with my Portuguese passport. However, my sister's passport has expired and she has only her Portuguese national ID card (*cartão de cidadão*). Would she be able to leave the UK and travel to Germany with her national ID card, or would she need her Portuguese passport?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is fine.

An EU ID card is valid for entry into any EU member state - Wikipedia [specifically states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen_Card_(Portugal)) that the Cartao de Cidadao is a "valid travel document within all of Europe".

The only disadvantage of using an ID card is that you may not be able to use the e-Passport gates, so you may have to wait longer at passport control (this is definitely the case in the UK).

Comment: As for the UK, yes but we don't know about this will still be the case after 29th March 2019 - aka Brexit.

Comment: Also usable (I think) between Schengen countries that are not EU?

Comment: @WGroleau Indeed. Technically, it's possible in all countries covered by the EU freedom of movement. This does include all non-EU Schengen countries but one difference is that it was already true in Switzerland even before they joined the Schengen area.

Comment: @WGroleau As well as in the CEFTA states, Tunisia, Turkey and Georgia (Covid-19 restrictions notwithstanding).

Comment: @Crazydre I don't think that's generally the case in Turkey, it only applies to some EU citizens, not all EU/EEA/Swiss citizens whose country issues national ID card. Egypt also has similar rules. But all these are based on unilateral decisions and are fundamentally different.

Comment: @Relaxed Portuguese can use it for Turkey too, but also Egypt (forgot to mention that)

Comment: @Crazydre Yes but the answer and comments are about EU ID cards generally (the question was indeed narrower).